# Managing Caching, Service Failure handling when building Backend for frontend in API Gateway

Tags: architecture, microservices, node.js

I have 2 microservices.

1. Users Service - REST API which provides user detail
2. Statistics Service - REST API to provide different stats

My goal is to provide a single interface to a Mobile App which will be used by our users to see the stats. The stats should be shown to user according to his roles.

I think [API Gateway with Backend-For-Frontend](https://microservices.io/patterns/apigateway.html) variation is something have to build.

The API Flow will be like this.

```
[Mobile App]            [API Gateway]                           [User Microservice]             [Stats Microservice]
|                         |                                        |                                    |   
1---------Get Metrics---->|                                        |                                    |
                          2--------- Get User Roles -------------->|                                    |
                          3----------------------------Get Stats According to Roles-------------------->|
                          4(Wrap data in FrontEnd json)
<---Send JSON to App------5
```

I am thinking of using nodejs for this as most of our team members are have already worked on nodejs.
There are some good API Gateway out there like ExpressGateway, fast-gateway in nodejs. But both of them do not provide Data Aggregation ( Combining and Transforming data from multiple services) feature.

I can understand the Data Aggregation can become very use case specific hence there is not much support from these open source API Gateways, but I have not found any guidelines on how to achieve this with API Gateways.

I want to know how do we leverage Caching mechanism provided by API gateway if I write custom aggregation plugin/code to call the microservices.

I also want to know how to leverage Failure Handling provided by API gateway when Statistics Microservice is down.

Comment: 3 downvotes without any comment! Is there something wrong with the question. It will be great if someone can highlight the problems.

Answer (score 0):

You stated that you will likely have to implement individual backends for different frontends. You also noticed that existing API Gateways don't have much support for data aggregation. I personally don't think that the Backend-for-Frontend (BFF) pattern is a variation of the API Gateway. From my perspective, BFFs can contain business logic (e.g. aggregation of different data sources to provide enriched information to the frontend), whereas an API Gateway generally does not contain business logic. Hence API Gateways are reusable, but BFFs are not reusable. For the rest of the answer, I assume that you want to follow the BFF pattern.

## Caching

My understanding is that you want to cache requests from the frontend to the BFF in order to avoid overloading the user service and the statistics service. That means you want to cache aggregated data.

The caching could be implemented as a separate layer, for example by putting a reverse proxy between mobile app and BFF that caches GET requests to the BFF API. The reverse proxy will reduce the amount of development work and it can be used for TLS termination. The drawback is increased operational complexity.

It is up to you if you prefer one cache per BFF or a single cache for all BFFs (just like an API Gateway :).

If the frontends send requests to the backend that are not easily cachable by a reverse proxy, (e.g. WebSocket connection, GraphQL API), the cache could be implemented as part of the BFF. This will reduce operational complexity, but you will have to implement the cache for each BFF individually.

## Handling downtime of the statistics service

If the frontend requests user statistics which are not cached and the statistics service is unavailable, you have no choice but to send an error response to the frontend. Breaking up the dependency from the BFFs to the statistics service would be a significant architectural change.